# Sum Based on Grouping and Order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have raw data similar to below ...

```
WO  OP  WC          Time
1   10  Band Saw    2.0
1   15  Band Saw    5.0
1   17  Band Saw    10.0
1   20  CNC Lathe   6.0
1   22  Band Saw    102.0
1   30  Inspection  33.0
2   10  Band Saw    1.5
2   20  CNC Lathe   6.00
2   20  CNC Lathe   2.00
2   30  CNC Punch   0.5
2   40  Manual Ops  1.25
2   50  Inspection  0.00
```

I need it to Sum and Group like below.  ie summing the Time for the WO/WC column until the WC changes, not a total for the overall WO.  Hope I have explained that clearly enough (probably not)
We need to support SQL Server 2005.

```
WO  WC          Time
1   Band Saw    17.0
1   CNC Lathe   6.0
1   Band Saw    102.0
1   Inspection  33.0
2   Band Saw    1.5
2   CNC Lathe   8.00
2   CNC Punch   0.5
2   Manual Ops  1.25
2   Inspection  0.00
```

Comment: How do you end up with two Band Saw groups in work order 1?

Comment: @Xedni it looks as though the sort order is `WO, WC` and each grouping ends when WC changes, not as in a traditional `group by`

Comment: looks like he wants to group by only if the duplicates appear one after other but he is not giving us how he ir ordering the first result, chances are he don't give us the correct expected output or is not telling all the history

Comment: What version of SQL you running?

Comment: And remember, if you dont' used a order by to generate the first listing it's a heap, it got NO ordering at all, thus any attempt to use it's order to do some logic is futile

Comment: Xedni -Any SQL needs to be able to run in 2005.

Comment: Do you have an ordering column? Without an `ORDER BY` there's no guarantee that the data will be in any particular order.

Comment: Daniel E - this is exactly what I am looking for.  ie Sum the Time while the WC is the same.

Comment: Zoff Dino - I am ordering by WO and Op in the initial result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this. I build a row_number over the order you defined (WO and OP), Then, I build another row_number over each WC sorted by WO and OP. now you have two row_numbers. One over the entire set, and one over each WC. Now, when you subtract the latter from the former, you form groups wherever there is only 1 row difference, Each time there is MORe than one row, you get a new grouping. No recursion necessary.

```
;with t (WO, OP, WC, Time) as
(
select 1,   10,  'Band Saw',    2.0
union all select 1,   15,  'Band Saw',    5.0
union all select 1,   17,  'Band Saw',    10.0
union all select 1,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   6.0
union all select 1,   22,  'Band Saw',    102.0
union all select 1,   30,  'Inspection',  33.0
union all select 2,   10,  'Band Saw',    1.5
union all select 2,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   6.00
union all select 2,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   2.00
union all select 2,   30,  'CNC Punch',   0.5
union all select 2,   40,  'Manual Ops',  1.25
union all select 2,   50,  'Inspection',  0.00
), rn as
(

    select 
        grp= row_number() over (order by WO, op) - row_number() over (partition by wo, wc order by wo, op),
        *
    from t
)
select grp, wo, wc, sum(time)
from rn
group by grp, wo, wc
```

Edited to use one cte. Also fixed the partition in the second order by. This outperforms an rcte with the data provided and will probably scale better because it doesnt have to recurse an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: It actually makes no difference. Whether you reset the RID on every Work Order (as you suggest) or whether you sort the entire set (as in my case) you still get partitioned groups when you subtract the other row number.

Comment: Xedni - Thanks for the response and apologies for the delay getting back to you. This works to an extent, however the results are not in the correct order. For WO 1 the order I need the results to show is Band Saw, CNC Lathe then the 2nd Instance of the Band Saw.

Comment: Xedni - I have amended your answer slightly to give the desired results - I added a Max(Op) and ordered the results by WO and MaxOp.  Works really well - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH
    cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT  WO, OP, WC, Time,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY WO, Op) AS RowNumber
        FROM    MyTable
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT  WO, OP, WC, Time, RowNumber,
                1 AS GroupID
        FROM    cte1
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  cte1.WO, cte1.OP, cte1.WC, cte1.Time, cte1.RowNumber,
                CASE
                    WHEN cte1.WC = cte2.WC THEN cte2.GroupID
                    ELSE cte2.GroupID + 1
                END AS GroupID
        FROM    cte1
        INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.RowNumber = cte2.RowNumber + 1  
    )

SELECT  WO, WC, SUM(Time) As TotalTime
FROM    cte2
GROUP BY GroupID, WO, WC
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I don't have SQL Server 2005 around to test but it should work. If you want more details, query `cte1` and `cte2`.

Comment: Zoff Dino - Thanks for the response and apologies for the delay getting back to you.  This produces the desired results - it is a little slow with the real data I have, but it is a great start.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Xedni who supplied me with the bulk of the answer.  I had to add the Max(op) and the sort to his supplied solution.

```
;with t (WO, OP, WC, Time) as
    (
    select 1,   10,  'Band Saw',    2.0
    union all select 1,   15,  'Band Saw',    5.0
    union all select 1,   17,  'Band Saw',    10.0
    union all select 1,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   6.0
    union all select 1,   22,  'Band Saw',    102.0
    union all select 1,   30,  'Inspection',  33.0
    union all select 2,   10,  'Band Saw',    1.5
    union all select 2,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   6.00
    union all select 2,   20,  'CNC Lathe',   2.00
    union all select 2,   30,  'CNC Punch',   0.5
    union all select 2,   40,  'Manual Ops',  1.25
    union all select 2,   50,  'Inspection',  0.00
    ), rn as
    (

        select 
            grp= row_number() over (order by WO, op) - row_number() over (partition by wo, wc order by wo, op),
            *
        from t
    )
    select grp, wo, MAX(op) AS MaxOp, wc, sum(time)
    from rn
    group by grp, wo, wc
    ORDER BY wo, MaxOp
```